# How can I create a function that calls another function and passes in an instance attribute as an argument?

Tags: python, function, class, attributes, instance

I am fairly new to coding and am getting really confused with how to call one function from another. I am trying to pass in an instance attribute as an argument but keep getting a name error for 'getVal'. Is this an issue with the 'getVal' function or the argument I am trying to pass? 'self.Volume' is a list of numbers and 'self.num' is a list of binary numbers.

```
def getVal(self, solution):
    return [self.volume[i] for i in range(10) if solution[i]] 

def fitness(self): 
    print(getVal(self.num))
```

Comment: Please update your question with the full error traceback.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Close. You need to make sure you put `self.` before your calls to a class function. and no need to pass `self.num` into `getVal` you can just call it from inside `getVal`

```
def getVal(self):
    return [self.volume[i] for i in range(10) if self.num[i]] 

def fitness(self): 
    print(self.getVal())
```

Answer (score 5):

since `getVal()` and `fitness()` are class-functions, you need to call them with `self.`:

```
def fitness(self): 
    print(self.getVal(self.num))
```

Answer (score 4):

If this is within a class, then you have to refer to the method via `self.getVal()`. In Python, the instance is passed in as the first argument if you call its method, which is named `self` by convention. So to call the method, you have to either do `ClassName.getVal(self, self.num)` or `self.getVal(self.num)`.